# JS doesn't work in IE. The background image seems to repeat imperfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a JS module called "Cloud Zoom." It works quite nicely except in Internet Explorer.

But the example on Cloud Zoom's page works in all browsers! What am I doing so terribly wrong?

[My example. Works in all except for IE](http://forumgallery.rollinleonard.com/test3.php)

Comment: Any specific version of IE? All versions? What technology are you using for this? Pure JS? HTML 5?

Comment: IE 8, 7, 6 don't work.

Just the JS that came from "Professor Cloud." The link has the details about that.

Thanks!

Comment: I've added the `jquery` tag because I feel it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you followed the [instructions for integration](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom-integration.htm)?

Comment: I am very sure I have... Is it something to do with me centering the image in the div?